# Existe alguma maneira de estender um arquivo principal em Webforms?

Tags: c#, webforms, layout

Estou dando manutenção em uma aplicação antiga que utiliza Web Forms. Essa aplicação utiliza `Iframe` para fazer uma espécie de reutilização de layout.

O problema é que, mesmo fazendo isso, muito código está se repetindo, e eu gostaria de uma solução para isso.

Venho do PHP e Python, onde os frameworks utilizam layouts principais, que podem ser estendidos pelas views utilizadas. Eu não tenho ideia de como fazer isso em Web Forms (ou mesmo se é possível fazer isso).

Existe alguma maneira de utilizar um layout principal com arquivos ASPX? Como fazer isso?

Comment: Em WebForms você pode utilizar a MaterPage... mas não bate muito com o seu cenário do IFrame, porque esse isola o conteúdo dentro dele e não vai reutilizar nada...

Comment: @LeandroAngelo é o MasterPage mesmo, rapaz. Posta a resposta aí :D

Comment: conseguiu acertar sua master?

Answer (score 1):

O que você procura é chamado de MasterPage, nela ficam os componentes e elementos visuais que são compartilhados por todas as páginas da sua aplicação WebForms, segue abaixo um exemplo.

**Site.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Site" %>
 <html>

  <head>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <!-- Aqui vão as suas páginas de conteúdo-->
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Agora ao criar suas páginas de conteúdo que deverão ser apresentadas por esse template você deve declara-lo como tal.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" ... %>
```